# Show Next/Previous item of an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm writing the first item of an array to the screen, and would like to create `Next/Previous` buttons for array, but I can't get it to work. I have tried several methods, but I can't find suitable solution.

Can anyone help?

This is the last one I have tried:

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
sav = new Array(
"first item",
 "second item",
 "third item", 
 ); 

document.write(sav[0] + " <br>"); 
</script>
</div>

<div>
<a href="" onClick="javascript: sav[i++]">Previous</a>
<a href="" onClick="javascript: sav[i--]">Next!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you alaborate? why are you using anchors for this? write a function for handling onClick event and do whatever you want to do in it

Comment: What do you expect `javascript: sav[i++]` does?

Comment: One more example: http://jsfiddle.net/7mzzep4m/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Say you have an *Array* `var arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];`.
If you want to dynamically choose items from this *Array*, you'll need a new variable. Let's call this `i` and give it a default value `var i = 0;`

So far, `arr[i]; // "foo" (i === 0)`

---

### Next and Previous

Now, lets write a function to choose the next item by modifying `i`. We may want to consider what we want to happen when `i` is bigger than (or equal to) `arr.length` as well.

```
function nextItem() {
    i = i + 1; // increase i by one
    i = i % arr.length; // if we've gone too high, start from `0` again
    return arr[i]; // give us back the item of where we are now
}
```

Next, lets do the reverse, this time we might want to consider what should happen for negative `i`

```
function prevItem() {
    if (i === 0) { // i would become 0
        i = arr.length; // so put it at the other end of the array
    }
    i = i - 1; // decrease by one
    return arr[i]; // give us back the item of where we are now
}
```

So far,

```
nextItem(); // "bar" (i === 1)
prevItem(); // "foo" (i === 0 as we did `0 + 1 - 1`)
// also
prevItem(); // "baz" (decreased on 0)
nextItem(); // "foo" (increased at end of arr)
```

Great, so we've got the basic algorithms down.

---

### Connecting this to the *DOM*

First thing to note is that `document.write` is nearly always a bad idea. Instead, why not give our *Elements* some **unique** *id attributes* and use *DOM* methods in *JavaScript* **after the *Elements* exist**.

```html
<div id="output"></div>

<div>
    <span id="prev_button">Previous</span>
    <span id="next_button">Next!</span>
</div>
```

So now we can access the first `<div>` in *JavaScript* as `document.getElementById('output')`, and the two `<span>`s similarly.

Now, let's set the initial text in the `<div>`, this is quite easy

```
document.getElementById('output').textContent = arr[0]; // initial value
// if i is still at it's default value, we could have used i instead of 0
```

Next, we need to add [***event listeners***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to the `<span>`s so they perform an action. The handler of each will set the text of the `<div>` in a similar way to above, but using the relevant *function* from earlier.

```
document.getElementById('prev_button').addEventListener(
    'click', // we want to listen for a click
    function (e) { // the e here is the event itself
        document.getElementById('output').textContent = prevItem();
    }
);

document.getElementById('next_button').addEventListener(
    'click', // we want to listen for a click
    function (e) { // the e here is the event itself
        document.getElementById('output').textContent = nextItem();
    }
);
```

This is great! Now the only thing left to do is make sure it runs "after the *Elements* exist". There are two ways to do this, either by putting the `<script>` element after the elements it uses, or by listening for the *load event* on window, i.e.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // DOM related JavaScript goes here
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hrzshpma/) of everything together

---

If you want to do this multiple times or are mixing it with other *JavaScript*, you may need to consider variable name conflicts. The easiest way to get around this is by using an *IIFE* to create a "safe place" for your variables, but this answer is already long enough.

Comment: what if we want to hide the `previous` when we get to first element and hide the `next` button when we get the last element?

Comment: how to do in angular with GET API. I got 10 arrays in API and display one at a time and a button for doing the same which is `<<     2/10      >>`

Comment: To hide next / previous I did the following (In angular, but might help you in the right direction)

<button (click)="previous()" *ngIf="i != 0">Previous</button>
<button (click)="next()" *ngIf="arr.length != i + 1">Next</button>

Answer (score 2):

Try this way easier and corrected.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    var text = [
        "first item",
        "second item",
        "third item"
    ]; 

    var Current = 0;

    document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = text[Current];

    function Prev(){
        if(Current == 0){
            Current = text.length - 1;}
        else{
            Current--;}

        document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = text[Current];
    }

    function Next(){
        if(Current == text.length - 1){
            Current = 0}
        else{
            Current++;}

        document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = text[Current];
    }

</script>

<div id="textHere"></div>

<div>
    <button onclick="Next();">Next!</button>
    <button onclick="Prev();">Previous</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this way, easier and corrected. -Alfa College Application Developer.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    var text = [
        "first item",
        "second item",
        "third item"
    ]; 

    var Current = 0;

    document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = text[Current];

    function Prev(){
        if(Current == 0){
            Current = text.length - 1;}
        else{
            Current--;}

        document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = text[Current];
    }

    function Next(){
        if(Current == text.length - 1){
            Current = 0}
        else{
            Current++;}

        document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = text[Current];
    }

</script>

<div id="textHere"></div>

<div>
    <button onclick="Next();">Next!</button>
    <button onclick="Prev();">Previous</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Only difference I found between this and @DOTNET Team's answer is "-Alfa College Application Developer.". Seriously?!

Comment: lmao, they used my comment and they didn't post mine, i posted mine again a little time ago when one of my friends needed this answer.